# Use sympy.solve with np.deg2rad in equation

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to use sympy.solve to solve an equation to a variable. Inside of the equation there is 'np.deg2rad', 'np.tan' and 'np.pi'. For example I want the equation 'a-np.tan(np.deg2rad(b))*np.pi' solved for a. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sympy as sy

a,b = sy.symbols('a b')
sy.solve(a-np.tan(np.deg2rad(b))*np.pi, a)
```

When I try it I get the following Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'deg2rad'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [79] in <cell line: 1>
    sy.solve(a-np.tan(np.deg2rad(b))*np.pi, a)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable deg2rad method
```

I tried to replace these parts. For example 'numpy_tan' instead of np.tan so I can solve it and replace it then again. This is my second Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sympy as sy

numpy_tan,numpy_deg2rad,numpy_pi,a,b = sy.symbols('numpy_tan numpy_deg2rad numpy_pi a b')
sy.solve(a-numpy_tan(numpy_deg2rad(b))*numpy_pi, a)
```

When I do that I get a different Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [81] in <cell line: 1>
    sy.solve(a-numpy_tan(numpy_deg2rad(b))*numpy_pi, a)

TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable
```

What can I do to make it work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to solve an equation symbolically then you should use the symbolic routines from SymPy. NumPy's functions like `deg2rad` etc cannot work with symbols:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sym

In [2]: a, b = sym.symbols('a, b')

In [4]: sym.solve(a - sym.tan(b*sym.pi/180)*sym.pi, a)
Out[4]: 
⎡     ⎛π⋅b⎞⎤
⎢π⋅tan⎜───⎟⎥
⎣     ⎝180⎠⎦
```

Comment: Also, SymPy equivalent to `np.deg2rad` is `rad`. SymPy equivalent to `np.rad2deg` is `deg`.